# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' df_data = df[columns]

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import multiple sheets from excel file but it giving me  " unhashable type: 'list' " error.

```
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

columns = ['SR_NO', 'NTN', 'NAME']
df_data = df[columns]
records = df_data.values.tolist()
```

NOTE: For the single sheet its working fine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "For the single sheet its working fine" Well, *what do you actually want to happen*? The file doesn't have columns; sheets do. Does every sheet have all of those columns? How do you want the results to be organized? Please read [ask] and try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, you could show the exact content of each sheet (for a small amount of data, with two example sheets), and show the exact corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use `sheet_name=None` then get dictionary of DataFrames for each sheetname with keys by sheetname texts.

So if need specify `sheet_name` use:

```
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', sheet_name='my_sheet')
```

Or for first:

```
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx')
```

If need processing all sheetnames converted to `DataFrame`s:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

#for test sheetnames
print (dfs.keys())

d = {}
for k, v in dfs.items():
    columns = ['SR_NO', 'NTN', 'NAME']
    df_data = v[columns]
    records = df_data.values.tolist()
    d[k] = records

#for test sheetnames
print (d.keys())

print (d['my_sheet'])
```

---

```
d = {k: v[['SR_NO', 'NTN', 'NAME']].values.tolist() 
        for k, v in  pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', sheet_name=None).items()}
```

Comment: dfs = pd.read_excel('sample501.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

for k, v in dfs.items():
    columns = ['SR_NO', 'NTN', 'NAME']
    df_data = v[columns]
    records = df_data.values.tolist()
    d[k] = records
Its working but still its reading 1 sheet(last sheet) from my excel file

Comment: @MuhammadOsama - What is `print (d.keys())` ?

Comment: print (d['Sheet2'])

Comment: @MuhammadOsama - I see copy my code. But I have no answer what is `What is print (d.keys())` ?

Comment: Ouh my bad, in reponse of print (dfs.keys()) it showing:
dict_keys(['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'])
But in database only one random sheet from all being updated

Comment: Its reading all the sheet from my excel file but writing only the last one

Answer (score 1):

Muhammad Osama, welcome to stack overflow.

I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve, but from my understanding, see if this snippet of code will help:

```
import pandas as pd

my_sheet_list = ['Worksheet']

for sheet in my_sheet_list:
    df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet)
    line_count = 0
    for row in df:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            print(f'row 1: {row[1]}')
            line_count += 1
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

This will loop over all sheet names in an Excel file, you will have to manually input the sheet names in my_sheet_list.
It will first print the columns (headers) and then it will continue and you can grab any information that you need based on the column numbers in the row.

Is this helping you ?